# Is there any mistake in this code to make memory leak?

Tags: php

I tried more than a time but every time gives the same error.

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 507510784) (tried to allocate 16384 bytes) in ..(location)..\accounts.php on line 51
```

The function

```
public function getUser($userBase, $allowID = true, $allowUName = true, $allowEmail = true, $allowHash = true) {
            // If nothing allowed!
            if ($allowID == false && $allowUName == false && $allowEmail == false && $allowHash == false) {
                return NULL;
            }
            if ( $allowID == true ) {
                // User ID
                $result = $this->conn->query( "SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `id` = {$userBase}" );
                if ( $result && $result->num_rows > 0 ) {
                    return new user( $this->conn, $userBase );
                }
            }
            if ( $allowUName == true ) {
                // User Name
                $result = $this->conn->query( "SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `username` = '{$userBase}'" );
                if ( $result && $result->num_rows > 0 ) {
                    return new user( $this->conn, $userBase );
                }
            }
            if ( $allowEmail == true ) {
                // Email
                $result = $this->conn->query( "SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `email` = '{$userBase}'" );
                if ( $result && $result->num_rows > 0 ) {
                    return new user( $this->conn, $userBase );
                }
            }
            if ( $allowHash == true ) {
                $result = $this->conn->query( "SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `hash` = '{$userBase}'" );
                if ( $result && $result->num_rows > 0 ) {
                    return new user( $this->conn, $userBase );
                }
            }
            return NULL;
        }
```

And this is how I do call it.

```
return this->getUser($uname, false, true, true, false);
```

I don't know the reason why it uses this huge memory.

Comment: Something you're doing before this is using large amounts of memory; this is simply the straw that breaks the camel's back

Comment: nothing, actually nothing.

Comment: Well then nothing is using 507,510,784 bytes of memory

Comment: @MarkBaker I have added whole the function for more details.

Comment: What else is your script doing besides calling `getUser()`? Are you loading any other database records into memory?

Comment: Nothing calling getUser() expect this, That's why I don't understand, It worked in register page while not in login, I use the same code on both pages.

Comment: @Phoenix It's line after line commented "// User Name"

Comment: @MarkBaker If you want privately take a look at the whole code, there is no problem!

Comment: Bump, I am still facing this problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well so far, I understood the problem

The line containg new user which connects to database and loads it self again which causes an infinite loop trying to reach a result then fails!